# Notification email for p4 changes submitted by myself

Tags: perforce

I do get a notification email whenever a changelist is submitted by any other user that edits, deletes, or adds files that match my "p4 user" form "Reviews:" specification.

However, I don’t get notification email from perforce when I myself submit to these locations. Is there any way to get such notification mails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't mention which review daemon script you're using (there are several).

In the most-common review daemon script (p4review.py), look for:

```
send_to_author = 0
# Set to 1 to CC: email to the original author of the changelist or job
```